# term for gibberish intended to resemble specific language

Tags: phonetics, orthography

**Is any term identified, among linguists, for an effect by which some speech or text has no meaning, and yet superficially resembles, by following certain   patterns, speech or text from
a particular language or language group?**

The following are  examples to illustrate the concept:

1. Consider the following meaningless text:

   > Furgle blunkers manergatation

   Assuming that the text was written with an intention to follow English orthographic patterns, you probably can infer an intended pronunciation, even though you recognize no word from those you have learned.

   Imagine trying to teach someone to reproduce the speech and text from memory. One might speculate that such a task is much easier in the case that a person is familiar with English, compared to the case that  a person has had no exposure, because of the superficial resemblance between the  phonetic  and orthographic structure of the sample and that of   speech or text understood as English.
2. A [comedy sketch](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0BzGlfm1wFo), performed by American comedians Keegan-Michael Key and Jordan Peele, attempts to lampoon how an English speaker might experience speech of the French language. The humor of the sketch depends on a gimmick, by which the audience hears speech that some incorrectly may believe is   understood as French.

   (The illusion is enhanced by the early inclusion of the widely-recognized French expressions *[merci beaucoup](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/merci_beaucoup)* and *[très bien](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/tr%C3%A8s_bien)*.)
3. Italian singer Adriano Celentano, in 1972, released [Prisencolinensinainciusol](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prisencolinensinainciusol),  a song explained
   as "intended to sound to its Italian audience as if it is sung in English spoken with an American accent, vaguely reminiscent of Bob Dylan; however, the lyrics are deliberately unintelligible gibberish with the exception of the words 'all right'."

   (A [dance performance](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_g6YxkSqL20) of the musical piece, in collaboration with Italian dancer Raffaella Carrà, additionally parodies visual features of certain American performing styles.)

   (Thank you to user **@livresque** for providing this additional example.)

Comment: The closest thing I can think of is [glossolalia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Glossolalia).

Comment: There’s a similar short film (very short, like a minute or two I think) that does the same in English. Made by some Australians, I think. A young couple having some sort of argument/emotional scene over dinner – all seems like you understand them because it sounds exactly like Broadcast American, but it’s actually gibberish. Can’t remember what it’s called though.

Comment: In _Surely You're Joking, Mr Feynman_ he talks about his talent for doing this in particular languages. I don't know a name for it, though.

Comment: *Prisencolinensinainciusol* by Adriano Celentano in Italian and *The Universal Language* by David Ives both come to mind.  Are these just false cognates?

Comment: @livresque: Thank you for the reference to Prisencolinensinainciusol. It is an appropriate example, and I have integrated it into the question.

Comment: "Godël, Escherman and Bach: An Eternal Golden Braid" has some beautiful renditions of "Jabberwocky", a poem of half-gibberishin (some of which has since been integrated to the Lexicon) in [German](http://www76.pair.com/keithlim/jabberwocky/poem/hofstadter.html). Ebyan Álvarez has "translated" it well to [Spanish](http://www.nolithius.com/articles/misc/jabberwocky-in-spanish), too. Ah, a [list](http://www76.pair.com/keithlim/jabberwocky/translations/) of translations is available!

Comment: @PeterOlson you should make "glossolalia" an answer--there's a similar question on [ELU](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/290219/is-there-a-word-for-imitating-language-sound) with some good answers.

Comment: @Conrado I thought of that in a staircase mind, the translations of "Jabberwocky" and how appropriate that this is asking the ?opposite of portmanteau.

Comment: *Jabberwocky* employs fictional words, much the same as fantasy and science-fiction literature, but is undeniably a work of writing in the English language, as directly evidenced by the possibility of translation into German or any other real language, as well as the by the reader's ability to follow an essential story line. It is an interesting example, but perhaps distinct from the framing of the current question.

Comment: @PeterOlson After having absorbed a bit more information, I have reconsidered my position on Glossolalia. Now I think that it is not the ideal answer, because it is the term applied to the event at Pentecost described in Acts 2. An integral part of that story is that the people who heard the "other tongues" (glossolalia) **understood** them, while OP's question includes "meaningless".

Comment: @Conrado: The relevant consideration for whether *glossolalia* is an applicable term is the understanding linguists give to it, not the original source text from which the term is borrowed. The linguistics usage of the term entails spontaneous vocalization that lacks any clear intention known the speaker. This activity contrasts against the kind described in the question, a systematic and deliberate process of mimicking features of a particular, actual, natural language.

Comment: I've always heard it called _doubletalk_. The late [Prof. Irwin Corey](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Irwin_Corey) -- "The World's Foremost Authority" -- was a master of this genre.

Answer (score 8):

> [**Grammelot**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grammelot) (or gromalot or galimatias) /ˈɡrɒməlɒt/ is an imitation of language used in satirical theatre, an ad hoc gibberish that uses prosody along with macaronic and onomatopoeic elements to convey emotional and other meaning, and used in association with mime and mimicry.

A romance grammelot (sometimes dubbed "Cirquish") is famously used by Cirque du Soleil, e.g. [Pearl](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Hh7Kbxem25A).

Comment: Great find! ... +1

Comment: Does the term represent an instance of an imitation of *some particular target language*, or only *language generally*? (An important feature of the Key & Peele and Celentano examples is that an observer with familiarity but not understanding of the target language might make the inaccurate inference that the speech is authentic.)

Answer (score 2):

I only know a term from typography for that thing, it is [greeking](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/greeking). In typography greeking is used to demonstrate layout and fonts without distracting the judges by the contents of the text. Maybe, it's this word you remember.

Comment: I considered using [Lorem ipsum](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lorem_ipsum) as an example, but it seems to be based on a corrupted source text, and not a deliberate attempt to mimic Latin.

Answer (score -1):

I don't know what the technical terms in linguistics would be, but the phenomenon you describe has several possible variations and there are a set of denominations for it.

[Apparently each language has its own word for it](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pig_Latin#In_other_languages).

[Pig Latin (taken from wikipedia)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pig_Latin):

> Early mentions of pig Latin or hog Latin describe what we would today call dog Latin, a type of parody Latin.[citation needed] Examples of this predate even Shakespeare, whose 1598 play, Love's Labour's Lost, includes a reference to dog Latin:[2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pig_Latin#In_other_languages)

> Costard: Go to; thou hast it ad dungill, at the fingers' ends, as they say.
> Holofernes: O, I smell false Latine; dunghill for unguem.
> — Love's Labour's Lost, William Shakespeare

Comment: @epl **from the OP** "and yet superficially resembles, by following certain patterns, speech or text from a particular language or language group?"

Comment: "Has no meaning" means without any possibility of being a method of communication.